# accessing static method across plugins

Tags: java

I have two plugins pluginA, and pluginB, which are using SDK from a platform C. Obviously pluginA and pluginB would not be able to access methods from each other, and any communication between pluginA and pluginB must be via C.

pluginA has a utility class utilA , which has a static method getMethod() which will be used in pluginB. and returns an object of a class which is also in pluginB itself. I can create any interface/factory class , in platform C, so that this communication can be done.

Can someone suggest how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Factory design pattern.  The factory should be a resource accessible from the SDK to all "plugins" and the SDK should decide (perhaps with a settings file or annotations) which plugin becomes the supplier for the factory.

One other design thought.  I prefer to use interfaces as the output of a Factory object.  That way one class can implement the interface any way it likes, and every other class (no matter when created, or how loaded by the ClassLoader) can use that factory.  This may save you a bunch of headaches at testing or runtime.